# Can this set define the graph of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Consider a function of the type $y=f(x)$. This means the function is surjective: every element of its co-domain is an image of one or more objects of its domain (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I've been told that a graph of such function can be described as this set: $$\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\left(y+1\right)^2=y^2\right\}$$

Now I can't get my head around this. Let me tell you what I can get from this. The set of all points belongs to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane such that they can be found in the line $y=-\frac{1}{2}$. Why does this make sense?

Also, why is this set not applicable: $$\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\left(x-1\right)^2=x^2\right\}$$?

Comment: Your second sentence is false; for instance, $y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ has the given form, but is not surjective onto the reals, because $0 < f(x) \le 1$ for every $x$.

Comment: Also: whoever told you that the graph could be described as that set...was probably mistaken, unless there's quite a lot missing from the information you've given us.

Comment: @JohnHughes It comes from an exercise given to me; I'll cite it (translated): "Which of the following sets of points can be the graph of a function y=f(x)?". The correct answer is supposedly the first set I presented. Why: I can't tell...

Answer (score 1):

A set $G\subset X\cdot Y$ is a graph of a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ when and only when $\forall x\in X$ there is one and only one  $y\in Y$ such that $\left(x,y\right)\in G$.So $\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\left(x-1\right)^2=x^2\right\}$ can never represent $G$, since it yields a line parallel to the $y-axis$: meaning, there are multiple images for one lonely $x$.

The set $\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\left(y+1\right)^2=y^2\right\}$ describes $G$ because it yields a line parallel to the $x-axis$: meaning, each value $x$ has one and only one image, although that image is the same for every $x$. That is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is, of course, a correct answer to a question that you didn't ask. Your question asks "Must the graph of a (surjective) function be this particular set?", and the answer to that is "no"; the dual question --- "**Can** the graph of a function be this particular set?" --- is really what was asked, and the answer to *that* question is "yes".  I suspect that some of the difficulty here is one of the subtleties of language rather than of mathematics, but you might want, in the future, to write the exact question followed by your thoughts, rather than your interpretation of the question.

Comment: Well, I did wrote the exact question in a comment. But yes, indeed it is a tricky question due to the language. The question seems to consider relevant to state the the graph is that of "a function y=f(x)",  and not merely "of a function" thus inducing me to think that it had something to do with it being surjective. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I really couldn't do better since I had limited understanding (math newbie), sorry for that.